# React: break dependency between 2 related contexts with top-level constant object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a new major release for [react-xarrows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xarrows), and I came up with some messy situation.

It's not going to be simple to explain, so let's start with visualization:

consider the next example - 2 draggable boxes with an arrow drawn between them, and a wrapping context around them.

[image]

focused code:

```js
<Xwrapper>
  <DraggableBox box={box} />
  <DraggableBox box={box2} />
  <Xarrow start={'box1'} end={'box2'} {...xarrowProps} />
</Xwrapper>
```

`Xwrapper` is the context, `DraggableBox` and `Xarrow` are, well, you can guess.

### My goal

I want to trigger a render on the arrow, and solely on the arrow, whenever one of the connected boxes renders.

### My approach

I want to be able to rerender the arrow from the boxes, so I have to consume 'rerender arrow'(let's call it `updateXarrow`) function on the boxes, we can use a context and a `useContext` hook on the boxes to get this function.
I will call `XelemContext` to the boxes context.

also, I need to consume `useContext` on `Xarrow` because I want to cause a render on the arrow whenever I decide.

this must be 2 different contexts(so I could render xarrow solely). one on the boxes to consume 'updateXarrow', and a different context consumed on Xarrow to trigger the reredner.

so how can I pass this function from one context to another? well, I can't without making an infinite loop(or maybe I can but could not figure it out), so I used a local top-level object called `updateRef`.

```js
// define a global object
const updateRef = { func: null };

const XarrowProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // define updateXarrow here
  ...
  // assign to updateRef.func
  updateRef.func = updateXarrow;
  return <XarrowContext.Provider value={updateXarrow}>{children}</XarrowContext.Provider>;
};

//now updateRef.func is defined because XelemProvider defined later
const XelemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <XelemContext.Provider value={updateRef.func}>{children}</XelemContext.Provider>;
};
```

the thing is, that this object is not managed by react, and also, i will need to handle cases where there is multiple instances of `Xwrapper`, and I'm leaving the realm of React, so i have 2 main questions:

1. there is a better approach? maybe I can someone achieve my goal without going crazy?
2. if there is no better option, is this dangerous? I don't want to release a code that will break on edge cases on my lib consumer's apps.

### Code

##### DraggableBox

```js
const DraggableBox = ({ box }) => {
  console.log('DraggableBox render', box.id);
  const handleDrag = () => {
    console.log('onDrag');
    updateXarrow();
  };
  const updateXarrow = useXarrow();
  return (
    <Draggable onDrag={handleDrag} onStop={handleDrag}>
      <div id={box.id} style={{ ...boxStyle, position: 'absolute', left: box.x, top: box.y }}>
        {box.id}
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
};
```

##### useXarrow

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {  XelemContext } from './Xwrapper';

const useXarrow = () => {
  const [, setRender] = useState({});
  const reRender = () => setRender({});

  const updateXarrow = useContext(XelemContext);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    updateXarrow();
  });
  return reRender;
};

export default useXarrow;
```

##### Xwrapper

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const XelemContext = React.createContext(null as () => void);
export const XarrowContext = React.createContext(null as () => void);

const updateRef = { func: null };

const XarrowProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('XarrowProvider');
  const [, setRender] = useState({});
  const updateXarrow = () => setRender({});
  updateRef.func = updateXarrow;
  return <XarrowContext.Provider value={updateXarrow}>{children}</XarrowContext.Provider>;
};

const XelemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('XelemProvider');
  return <XelemContext.Provider value={updateRef.func}>{children}</XelemContext.Provider>;
};

const Xwrapper = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('Xwrapper');
  return (
    <XarrowProvider>
      <XelemProvider>{children}</XelemProvider>
    </XarrowProvider>
  );
};

export default Xwrapper;
```

```js
const Xarrow: React.FC<xarrowPropsType> = (props: xarrowPropsType) => {
  useContext(XarrowContext);

  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  ....(more 1100 lines of code)
```

##### logs

I left some logs.

on drag event of a single box you will get:

```
onDrag
DraggableBox render box2
XarrowProvider
xarrow
```

#### Note

currently, this is working as expected.

### Update

after many hours of testing, this seems to work perfectly fine. I manage my own object that remember the update function for each Xwrapper instance, and this breaks the dependency between the 2 contexts. I will leave this post in case someone else will also come across this issue.

### Update (bad one)

this architecture breaks on react-trees with <React.StrictMode>...</React.StrictMode> :cry:

any idea why? any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in case someone would need something similar: here's a version that will work even with react strictmode(basically being rellyed of effect which called once and not renders):

```js
import React, { FC, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const XelemContext = React.createContext(null as () => void);
export const XarrowContext = React.createContext(null as () => void);

// will hold a object of ids:references to updateXarrow functions of different Xwrapper instances over time
const updateRef = {};
let updateRefCount = 0;

const XarrowProvider: FC<{ instanceCount: React.MutableRefObject<number> }> = ({ children, instanceCount }) => {
  const [, setRender] = useState({});
  const updateXarrow = () => setRender({});
  useEffect(() => {
    instanceCount.current = updateRefCount; // so this instance would know what is id
    updateRef[instanceCount.current] = updateXarrow;
  }, []);
  // log('XarrowProvider', updateRefCount);
  return <XarrowContext.Provider value={updateXarrow}>{children}</XarrowContext.Provider>;
};

// renders only once and should always provide the right update function
const XelemProvider = ({ children, instanceCount }) => {
  return <XelemContext.Provider value={updateRef[instanceCount.current]}>{children}</XelemContext.Provider>;
};

const Xwrapper = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('wrapper here!');
  const instanceCount = useRef(updateRefCount);
  const [, setRender] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    updateRefCount++;
    setRender({});
    return () => {
      delete updateRef[instanceCount.current];
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <XelemProvider instanceCount={instanceCount}>
      <XarrowProvider instanceCount={instanceCount}>{children}</XarrowProvider>
    </XelemProvider>
  );
};

export default Xwrapper;
```